# Elasticsearch document assosiations

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way in Elasticsearch to associate two documents to basically say: "These two belong together".

For example, I want to be able to associate TCP packets that are part of the same stream, so if I get a SYN and a SYN-ACK, I want to say that these two packets are related to each other.

Finally, I wish to be able to say: "Give me all the SYN packets which dont have a corresponding SYN-ACK".

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: Perhaps feeding the packets through a logstash aggregator would achieve this? Then I could group the packets into a "Stream index"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading your TCP events through Logstash, you can leverage the [`aggregate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html).

For instance, the filter configuration below will create a synthetic event on every `SYN` and "release" it on every `SYN-ACK`. You just need to identify a field `some_unique_id` that will bind both packets together as being related. Also make sure to see a proper `timeout` (here 120 seconds)

```
 filter {    
   if [type] == "SYN" {
     aggregate {
       task_id => "%{some_unique_id}"
       map_action => "create"
     }
   }

   if [type] == "SYN-ACK" {
     aggregate {
       task_id => "%{some_unique_id}"
       map_action => "update"
       end_of_task => true
       timeout => 120
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, What would the final document look like? Would it just be better to do an ES query when a SYN-ACK comes in?? Your help is very much appreciated..